# Filter specific word in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I'm pretty new to PySpark so I'm sorry if my question seems too simple but I've been bogged by it for some time now.

Given the following text is parallelized

> Alice has recently been troubled by recent events. It has come to Alice's attention that her grades were dipping down which worried Alice a lot. If Alice's parents were to find out about this, they would flip out. What should Alice do?

I know that to find the frequency of the word 'Alice' uses the code

```
rdd.filter(lambda x: "Alice" in x).count()
```

which is equal to 5. However, how do I exclude the the ones that are 'Alice's' and merely just get the word count of 'Alice', so my desired count should be 3 instead of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter only Alice using `.filter(lambda x:x[0]=='Alice')`

```
from operator import add
rdd.collect()
#["Alice has recently been troubled by recent events. It has come to Alice's attention that her grades were dipping down which worried Alice a lot. If Alice's parents were to find out about this, they would flip out. What should Alice do?"]

#filter only Alice
rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x.split(" ")).map(lambda x:(x,1)).reduceByKey(add).filter(lambda x:x[0]=='Alice').collect()  
#[('Alice', 3)]
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!! I've figured out the reason why I initially got an error!